# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'state_istuple'

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am working with tensorflow in python now.
And I've met an error which says **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'state_istuple'

Do you have any ideas of it?

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Please post code as code, not images

Comment: There is a typo

Comment: Refer to the API - it will indicate what keywords are accepted; then be diligent about honoring the rules. The error message says "the API is not being used correctly" - so go find out what expectation is incorrect per documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the keyword argument `state_is_tuple` instead of `state_istuple` for the `BasicLSTMCell` constructor as [documented](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/BasicLSTMCell#__init__).